# bind data to date using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Im using highcharts on client side application (I'm using on js with back-end calls for getting data).

anyway, the issue is:

first data series is from July 2012 - May 2013
second data series is from May 2012 - May 2013

the issue is that after loading the second data series, using Chart.addSeries({
name : 
color:
stack:
data:
})

it move backed the first data series to May even though its starting only on July.

I was trying using the date and convert them to timestamp but its not really help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've reproduced our example in the simple way http://jsfiddle.net/vL9Cf/ and I cannot find your issue, could you update my example with your code

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I came with is to load all the data for the first series, than the second data series. and only after having all the data to create the highchart.

if you have any solution where I can bind the Date to the column data, please let me know.

by the way, when using data like the following format it works.

this.Chart.addSeries({
            name: 'first data'
            color: '#' + arr[i].cms.global.graphColor,
            stack: 'first Stack',
            data: [[1,10][2,20][3,10]]
        });
this.Chart.addSeries({
            name: 'second data'
            color: '#' + arr[i].cms.global.graphColor,
            stack: 'second Stack',
            data: [[3,10][4,20][5,10]]
        });